# Is there an equivalent to pin SliverAppBar for BottomBar?

Tags: flutter

I can pin a SliverAppBar and then have a SliverList content scrolled under it. Is there an equivalent to have the list scroll under a BottomBar ?

The trick is that I want both AppBar and BottomBar pinned at the same time to have the scrolling effect.

This is the rendering of the AppBar

[image: AppBar rendering]

And this is the rendering of the Bottom
[image: Bottom render]

I'd like to diplay messages scroll under the text input and not have a filled color.

Is this possible ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom navigation bars don't normally scroll. Can you put your `BottomNavigationBar` in the `Scaffold`'s `bottomNavigationBar` slot and use an `AnimatedCrossFade` if you want to bring it in and out of view? If this doesn't solve your use case, please be more specific about the scrolling effect you want to achieve.

Edit: If you just want to position a widget at the bottom of the screen and have it stacked over your list, you can use a `Stack`.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}


class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  List<Widget> _items = new List.generate(60, (index) {
    return new Text("item $index");
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: [
          new ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            children: new UnmodifiableListView(_items),
          ),
          new Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: new AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              title: new Text('Sliver App Bar'),
            ),
          ),
          new Positioned(
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border.all(
                  width: 3.0,
                  color: Colors.blue.shade200.withOpacity(0.5)
                ),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                  new Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
              ),
              height: 40.0,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0)
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Added screenshots to get a better description of the case. Thanks Collin.

Comment: True, I started using Sliver to hide the bar then adopter the Google Allo style with opacity to hide, code can be simplified. Thanks for your help Collin.